# How to make an external module local

Tags: python, vim

My code depends on functions from a module `external_module` which is in my pythonpath path and which I include as

```
# global import
import external_module.sub_mod_one as smo
```

Now I want to share my code but I don't want to force my collaborators to checkout my other git repos and add them to their environment.

So, I thought I can copy the files to the local directory and rewrite the import as

```
# local import
import sub_mod_one as smo
```

However, since development goes on, I don't want to do this manually.

**Question** Is there a python module or vim plugin or something else that does this for me? Namely, copying the the included modules to the current folder and rewriting the import statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right" solution is to

1. properly package your "external_module" so it can be installed with pip,
2. add to your project(s) a pip requirements file referencing your package
3. then have everybody using virtualenvs

This way the package will be cleanly installed (and at the right version), you don't have to mess with your exports, and you dont have out of sync copies of your package everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I should get started with this. Is there a tutorial that explains how pip and github are used together?

Comment: This is an example on how to install a lib from git repo: `pip install git+git://github.com/user/project.git`

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional imports:

> ```
> try:
>     import external_module.sub_mod_one as smo                  
> except ImportError:
>     import sub_mod_one as smo
> ```

Comment: Can't you use Git for that?

Comment: This would mean combining several git repos. Looks a bit messy to me.